# How can I get mouse position with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, mouse-position

I want to get mouse *x* and *y* co-ordinates through JavaScript.  I have tried *pageX*, *pageY*, *clientX*, *clientY*, but nothing is displayed. I have tested this on both IE and Firefox.

Is there something I'm doing wrong in the following event?

```
var x=0;
var y=0;
function mouseDown(){
    alert("This is displayed");
    evt=event||window.event;
    alert(evt.clientX);
        alert(evt.clientY);
            alert(evt.pageX);
                alert(evt.pagey);
    alert("Flow doesn't reach here...");            
}
```

Comment: It's interesting that you use proper English in the strings in your code, but when asking for help on the Internet you shorten every word that's longer than 3 letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - you also need to hook the function up as an event handler.

Your event should take an event parameter:

```
function mouseDown(event) {
```

And then you need to tell the browser to call your function when the event occurs:

```
document.onmousedown = mouseDown;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not working because you are not listening for any events. You need to pass this function when any mouse events occur. Try my code below.. gets position on click

```
function getPos(evt) {
 evt = event || window.event;
 return {x:evt.clientX,y:evt.clientY};
}
```

Now you can just call this function inside an event listener like this.

```
addEventListener( 'click' , function(event) {
  var mousex = getPos(event).x;
  Var mousex = getPos(event).y;

  alert(mousex);alert(mousey);
});
```